# Why Microsoft force to use OneDrive in mysite

Tags: 2016, mysite

As it answered in  my previous question, I can't disable OneDrive in mysite

- why Microsoft add it as a mandatory option?
- Is there anyway to use only newsfeed and my profile info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the money. They want the users to use OneDrive. There's really nothing more to it. I for one don't quite get, why you would want to prevent the users from using onedrive. It's not like that option introduce anything they can't already do...

Comment: Because the company doesn't have budget for storage! Where can i set the  quota for OneDrive?

Comment: Ahh so it's not really the onedrive that's the issue, it's the storage tied to the mysite. OneDrive is merely a tool to access the files. I'm pretty sure you can manage the storage allocation of the mysite collection in central administration/Office 365 SharePoint administration :)